# css page does not connect proparley to the master page

Tags: html, css, master-pages

half of the css content doesn't apply to the master page
when i delete the css page and add the css code to the master page itself(without having two separate pages) the css works perfect

html

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MastrPage.master.cs" Inherits="Project.MastrPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta  charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <p class="logo">jhkjhk</p>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav_links">
                <li><a href="HtmlPage3.aspx">דף 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage2.aspx">דף 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="HtmlPage1.aspx">דף 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="#" class="cta"><button>dflksjf</button></a>
    </header>
    
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    <table width="100%" border="1" class="footer">
        <tr>
            <td>אוהד רונן</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   
</body>
</html>
```

as far as i know the css does not have a problem but here it is

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li, a, button {
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #edf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 10%;
    background-color: #24252A;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: goldenrod;
    font-size: 22px;
    order: 3;
}

.nav_links {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

nav {
    order: 2;
}

.cta {
    order: 1;
}

.nav_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px
}

.nav_links li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav_links li a:hover {
    color: #ddad34;
}

button {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
button:hover {
     background-color: #ddad34;
}


.content {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 44px;
    vertical-align: central;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 800px;
}

.footer {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 130px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: lightcyan;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

i really dont know what is the problem
the problem is between the connection of the css and the master page i already tried applying
this :href="~/StyleSheet.css"
it does not work either

edit:solution explorer
[image: solution explorer]

Comment: it could be better if you show your project structure (folders and files) in Solution Explorer or anywhere

Comment: added solution explorer

Comment: try `<link href="./StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server"/>` or `../`

Comment: doesn't work  );

Comment: its really weired

Comment: You can try it removing `runat="server"` it is forcing it to run only on the server. after updateing the CSS add it later.

Comment: still not applying

Comment: the runat attribute is also in the head. did you try after removing from there?

Comment: yes i did removed

Comment: when you run your project, do you see any errors in the developer console? and do you see StyleSheet.css reference at your running page source? there are 3 master pages in your project, is it possible to confuse them on any page?